# Как программно установить мargin?

Tags: java, android

Как программно в Java установить `margin` у `LinearLayout`?

Comment: [легко](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` является подклассом `LinearLayout.MarginLayoutParams`, у которого есть метод [`setMargins()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#setMargins(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). Поэтому всё просто:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = linearLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```